# Join DefaultIfEmpty() Error: The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting an error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type.

when there is no record in db.recordImages. I thought with a join (left) and `DefaultIfEmpty()` it would solve this.   When there is a record all works fine. Any ideas?

```
        var Val = (from c in db.recordOrders
                   join i in db.recordImages on c.ID equals i.recordNum into VImages
                   from b in VImages.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where c.ID == id

                   select new recordDetails
                   {
                       Image = b.Image,
                       ImageID = b.ID
                    }.ToList()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought with a join (left) and DefaultIfEmpty() it would solve this.

It would fix it, but the corresponding properties must be nullable, in this case ImageId must be a nullable property.

In your class change ImageId to a nullable int with `?`;

```
public int? ImageID {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it.  Makes sense. Appreciate it!!